# How to push resolve to an array with looping?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, promise

When I run the following code, there's some problem with my code.

**Expected result:**

```
['test0,'test1','test2']
```

**Actual result:**

```
['test3','test3','test3']
```

Code:

```js
var overall = [];

for(var a=0;a<3;a++){
    var test_promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log("looping: " + a);
            resolve('test' + a);
        },3000);
    });

    overall.push(test_promise);
}

Promise.all(overall).then(function(value){
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Reason to go with *Promises* + *SetTimeout*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix it , you should change **var**  to **let**  in for loop ( closure problem)

```
for(let a=0;a<3;a++)
```

The above result is because, var defines variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope.

> let allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the
>   block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike
>   the var keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an
>   entire function regardless of block scope.

for example

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
   setTimeout(function() {
       console.log('Value of i : ' + i); 
   },100);
}
```

The **desired output** of the above code is

```
Value of i : 1
Value of i : 2
Value of i : 3
Value of i : 4
Value of i : 5
```

But the **actual** output is

```
Value of i : 6
Value of i : 6
Value of i : 6
Value of i : 6
Value of i : 6
```

The above result is because, var defines variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope.

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

   setTimeout(function(){
       console.log('Value of i : ' + i);
   },100);
}
Output:
Value of i : 1
Value of i : 2
Value of i : 3
Value of i : 4
Value of i : 5
```

in your case, your code will be:

```
for(let a=0;a<3;a++){
    var test_promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log("looping: " + a);
            resolve('test' + a);
        },3000);
    });

    overall.push(test_promise);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `let` and pass the value into the promise like so:

```js
 

var overall = [];

for(let a=0;a<3;a++){
(aa => {
let test_promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("looping: " + a);
        resolve('test' + aa);
    },3000);
});

overall.push(test_promise);
})(a);
}

Promise.all(overall).then(function(value){
console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

quick answer: use `let a = 0` instead of `var a = 0`

longer answer: var is hoisted globalled and let and const are hoisted based on the current scope. 
So when you push to the array after the timeout, it tke the current value of `a` aka the last iteration of the for loop.
While using const or let, the value of a a the creattion of your promise will be used in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using var in for loop, use let. You can get the better idea about var and let from here [Difference between var and let?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

```js
var overall = [];

for(let a=0;a<3;a++){
    var test_promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log("looping: " + a);
            resolve('test' + a);
        },3000);
    });

    overall.push(test_promise);
}

Promise.all(overall).then(function(value){
    console.log(value);
});
```